# MS Sync/SQL Server Compact code fails in latest build, SQL Compact 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, synchronization, sql-server-ce

This is most unusual for me.

This code has always worked (several years), just recently I started getting this error:

> Method not found: 
>   Void Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeSyncProvider..ctor(System.String, System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection)'.

One of the main changes that I thought might have caused it was changing the target framework to .Net 4.6. But after changing back to 4.5.2, this is still an issue.

I am calling a class using this line:

```
e.Result = SyncLogic.Synchronize(e.Argument.ToString());
```

It doesn't enter this class (`SyncLogic`), however, and I assume the conflicting line is this:

```
orch = new SyncOrchestrator
{
  RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlServerConn),
  LocalProvider = new SqlCeSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlCeConn),
  Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Download
};
```

I have the same app installed (on my dev pc) and it works fine. Using a disassembler it appears to be using the same version of `Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe`, which is 3.1.0.0, Runtime Version v2.0.50727.

So I don't know how the same assembly could work for one build but not another.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify: "getting error" vs "it works fine"? Maybe some runtime component is missing on the "other" installation?

Comment: @ErikEJ I'm not sure I know how to answer you Erik, other than to say that the installed app, v. 4.46, syncs without any errors. I just tested this yesterday. But for my current project, it cannot run this code. I don't know what I've done or what changed to break what has been working for so long.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is actually a workaround rather than a solution. I don't know why had this problem, but I figured out that before my HD crashed the code worked. It was when I had to rebuild the project (because I lacked a recent backup) that the error started occurring.

The workaround was taking the older project, one that worked, keeping the references intact and copying in new code until it was up to date. So now I'm back in action but I really wish I knew why that error was happening since the references seemed to be identical. I need to let go of this anomaly and get on with life. Thanks for reading and learning this great moral lesson... keep your projects backed up!